# Looking for a game I played

Tags: identify-this-game

It has rounds like taboo. It has charades round. Talking without repetition round and couple of others

Desperate to find

Comment: Any substantive details you can provide: Format, materials, region of the world, etc?

Answer (score 1):

There is a party game called Celebrity, in which players write names of people on strips of paper and put them into a hat. There is then a sequence of rounds, and in each round someone takes one of the names out of the hat and tries to get others in the group to guess the name.

1. In the first round, clues can be anything that don't include the name itself.
2. In the second round, the clue must be a single word.
3. In the third round, the clue must be silent and use only actions.

There are then a bunch of alternative rounds that typically come after the third. The game has been released commercially at least twice - once as [Times Up!](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1353/times) (and Times Up! Title Recall), and once as [Monikers](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/156546/monikers).

The [Shut Up and Sit Down review of Monikers](http://www.shutupandsitdown.com/blog/post/review-monikers/) discusses some of the additional rounds, as well as a little about the history of the game.